# from list to matrix in r

Tags: r, list, matrix, dplyr

a list like this simulates some of my data, whereby a maching learning algorithm ranks input features according to their importance in predicting the response variable:

```
feature <- rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 3)
run <- c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 6), rep(3, 6))
rank <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3, 6, 5, 1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6)
testlist <- list(feature, run, rank)
```

I would like to end up with a matrix containing only the rank data, in the following form:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    4    5
[3,]    3    2    3
[4,]    4    3    4
[5,]    5    6    2
[6,]    6    5    6
```

but converting the lot to a matrix with `as.matrix()` does not produce the goods. I have also tried with `dplyr::group_by() %>% dplyr::pull()` but I still am failing to associate the `rank` with `run`.

Comment: `matrix(testlist[[3]],ncol=3)`

Comment: @maydin nice. also: ```matrix(testlist[[3]], ncol = length(testlist[[2]])/6)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to create the matrix based on `run` ?

```
do.call(cbind, split(testlist[[3]], testlist[[2]]))

#     1 2 3
#[1,] 1 1 1
#[2,] 2 4 5
#[3,] 3 2 3
#[4,] 4 3 4
#[5,] 5 6 2
#[6,] 6 5 6
```

Comment: yes I do, that works well thanks and doesn't hard code stuff

Answer (score 0):

We can use `unstack` in `base R`

```
unstack(data.frame(a = testlist[[3]], b = testlist[[2]]), a ~ b)
#  X1 X2 X3
#1  1  1  1
#2  2  4  5
#3  3  2  3
#4  4  3  4
#5  5  6  2
#6  6  5  6
```